# Hide command prompt containing open process without killing the process

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I'm running a server from a command prompt. I don't want the command prompt to be visible because other people in my house keep closing it, which shuts down the server. I need some extra scripting to hide it while keeping it running. An ideal solution would allow me to access the hidden prompt and then hide it again as needed.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF /I "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2%"=="64"  java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar "%~dp0craftbukkit- 0.0.1-snapshot.jar"
IF /I "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2%"=="86"  java -Xincgc -Xmx1024M -jar "%~dp0craftbukkit-0.0.1-snapshot.jar"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`start`-command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) to seperate a process you want to run from the terminal the batch file is running in.

But you will not be able to get the terminal back - if you need it for reading messages, pipe these to some file or use some software which allows you to hide windows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the command prompt isn't part of the server but is just the standard command prompt, then you should be able to avoid it altogether by getting rid of the batch file and using `JavaW` instead of `Java` to start your server.

So just execute the relevant command, either from the `Run` on the start menu, or from a command prompt you open manually.

So if you've got a 64 bit CPU it should be `javaw -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar "%~dp0craftbukkit- 0.0.1-snapshot.jar"`.
Otherwise it should be `javaw -Xincgc -Xmx1024M -jar "%~dp0craftbukkit-0.0.1-snapshot.jar"`.

Comment: well the batch file starts the server and in the cmd window it loads all achievments and loads the world so idk if the cmd is part of the server but ill try this

Comment: that didnt work :/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of tricks but I think any of them would either make it too easy for others to access or to annoying for you to access. I think your best bet would be to install something like [Power Menu](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-minimize-an-application-to-system-tray-in-windows/) and after you start window minimize it to the system tray. Easy to call and doesn't get in anyone's way so it is less likely to get closed by others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can hide it unless you write a small program that runs your server and minimises to the system tray.

How about:

```
@Echo Off
Title DO NOT CLOSE!!!
...
```